# How do I end a call properly in Twilio (using React)?

Tags: twilio

I'm building a web app and a mobile app which allow users to make calls to each other using Twilio. I have the basic functionality working fine, but ending the call is problematic - sometimes the web app user is left on the call even after clicking 'End Call'.  The mobile user can then rejoin the call and see the app user, even though the app user thinks they have finished the call.  Obviously this is potentially a huge problem.

My web app is built using React, and I've used the npm package twilio-video.

So, the web app has a button which the user can use to start a call, and this renders the following component. The remoteCaller is just an object with a 'name' and 'id' field; callEnded is a function from the calling component which hides the VideoCall component when the call is over.

```
const VideoCall = ({ remoteCaller, callEnded }) => {

  const roomName = `CreatedRoom_${remoteCaller.id}`

  const [call, setCall] = useState<CallObject>({
    accessToken: null,
    room: null,
    roomName,
    status: 'Starting'
  })
  const [controls, setControls] = useState<ControlObject>({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })
  const [localCaller, setLocalCaller] = useState({
    status: 'Unconnected',
    participant: null
  })
  const [remoteCaller, setRemoteCaller] = useState({
    name: remoteCaller.name,
    status: 'Unconnected',
    participant: null
  })

  const endCall = () => {
    if (localCaller.participant) {
      localCaller.participant.audioTracks.forEach((pub) => {
        pub.track.stop()
      })
      localCaller.participant.videoTracks.forEach((pub) => {
        pub.track.stop()
      })
    }
  }

  // Fetch Twilio token when screen loads
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      // Get access token
      const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_TOKEN_SERVICE}?identity=Clinician`
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${url}`, {
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
        })
        setError(null)
        setCall({ ...call, accessToken: response.data.accessToken, status: 'Connecting' })
      } catch {
        setError('Unable to connect to video service')
        setCall({ ...call, accessToken: null, status: 'Failed' })
      }
    }
    fetchToken()
  }, [])

  // When token has been obtained, attempt to connect call
  useEffect(() => {
    const connectToRoom = async () => {
      if (!call.accessToken) { return }

      const remoteConnected = (caller) => {
        setCall({ ...call, status: 'In Progress' })
        setRemoteCaller({ ...remoteCaller, participant: caller, status: 'Connected' })
      }

      const remoteDisconnected= () => {
        setCall({ ...call, status: 'Remote Disconnected' })
        setRemoteCaller({ ...remoteCaller, participant: null, status: 'Disconnected' })
      }

      // We have an access token.  Now start the call.
      Video
        .connect(call.accessToken, {
          name: call.roomName
        })
        .then((newRoom) => {
          setCall({ ...call, room: newRoom, status: 'Connected' })
          setLocalCaller({
            ...localCaller,
            participant: newRoom.localParticipant
          })
          setError(null)
          newRoom.on('participantConnected', remoteConnected)
          newRoom.on('participantDisconnected', remoteDisconnected)
          newRoom.participants.forEach(remoteConnected)
        })
    }

    if (!call.accessToken) { return undefined }
    connectToRoom()

    // Callback - clear up call once Local caller leaves
    return () => {
      endCall()
    }
  }, [call.accessToken])

  const handleToggleAudio = () => {
    setControls({ ...controls, audio: !controls.audio })
  }

  const handleToggleVideo = () => {
    setControls({ ...controls, video: !controls.video })
  }

  const handleEndCall = () => {
    if (call.room) { call.room.disconnect() }
    call.status = 'Ended'
    endCall()
    callEnded() // Return to previous screen
  }

  return (
    <div id="outerWrapper" className="callOuterWrapper">
      <div className="titleBar">
        <h1 className="pageHeader">
          Creating room with {remoteCaller.name}
          <span className="callStatus">
            (
            {call.status}
            )
          </span>
        </h1>
        <ControlBar
            controls={controls}
            endCall={handleEndCall}
            toggleAudio={handleToggleAudio}
            toggleVideo={handleToggleVideo}
        />
      </div>
      { call.room ? (
        <div className="videoRoom">
          {remoteCaller.status === 'Connected' ? (
            <div className="callWrapperDouble">
              { /* <RemoteCaller caller={remoteCaller} /> */ }
              <LocalCaller caller={localCaller} />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="callWrapperSingle">
              <div className="waitingMessage">Waiting for remote...</div>
              <LocalCaller caller={localCaller} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : null }
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoCall
```

LocalCaller is defined as:

```
const LocalCaller = ({ caller}) => {
  const [videoTracks, setVideoTracks] = useState([])
  const [audioTracks, setAudioTracks] = useState([])
  const videoRef = useRef(null)
  const audioRef = useRef(null)

  const trackAudioPubsToTracks = (trackMap: Map<string, LocalAudioTrackPublication>) => Array
    .from(trackMap.values())
    .map((publication:LocalAudioTrackPublication) => publication.track)
    .filter((track) => track !== null)

  const trackVideoPubsToTracks = (trackMap: Map<string, LocalVideoTrackPublication>) => Array
    .from(trackMap.values())
    .map((publication:LocalVideoTrackPublication) => publication.track)
    .filter((track) => track !== null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (caller.participant === null) { return undefined }

    // If a track has been subscribed to, add it to the appropriate
    //  track array (video or audio - data tracks are not used in Tuzzl)
    const trackSubscribed = (track:LocalTrack) => {
      switch (track.kind) {
        case 'audio':
          setAudioTracks((prev) => [...prev, track])
          break
        case 'video':
          setVideoTracks((prev) => [...prev, track])
          break
        default:
          break
      }
    }

    const trackUnsubscribed = (track:LocalTrack) => {
      switch (track.kind) {
        case 'audio':
          setAudioTracks((prev) => prev.filter((a) => a !== track))
          break
        case 'video':
          setVideoTracks((prev) => prev.filter((v) => v !== track))
          break
        default:
          break
      }
    }

    setVideoTracks(trackVideoPubsToTracks(caller.participant.videoTracks))
    setAudioTracks(trackAudioPubsToTracks(caller.participant.audioTracks))

    caller.participant.on('trackSubscribed', trackSubscribed)
    caller.participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', trackUnsubscribed)

    return () => {
      setVideoTracks([])
      setAudioTracks([])
      if (caller.participant) {
        caller.participant.removeAllListeners()
      }
    }
  }, [caller.participant])

  useEffect(() => {
    const videoTrack = videoTracks[0]
    if (videoTrack && videoRef && videoRef.current) {
      videoTrack.attach(videoRef.current)
    }
    return () => {
      if (videoTrack) {
        videoTrack.detach()
        videoTrack.stop()
      }
    }
  }, [videoTracks])

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioTrack = audioTracks[0]
    if (audioTrack && audioRef && audioRef.current) {
      audioTrack.attach(audioRef.current)
    }
    return () => {
      if (audioTrack) {
        audioTrack.detach()
      }
    }
  }, [audioTracks])

  return (
    <div className="caller">
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay />
      <audio ref={audioRef} autoPlay />
    </div>
  )
}

export default LocalCaller
```

ControlBar is:

```
const ControlBar = ({
  controls, toggleAudio, toggleVideo, endCall
}) => (
  <div className="videoControls">
    <button type="button" className="videoControlButton" onClick={toggleAudio}>
      {controls.audio ? <Mic /> : <MicOff />}
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="videoControlButton" onClick={toggleVideo}>
      {controls.video ? <Videocam /> : <VideocamOff />}
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="videoControlButton" onClick={endCall}>
      <CallEnd />
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default ControlBar
```

RemoteCaller is currently commented out, but it's basically the same as LocalCaller with Remote Tracks instead of Local ones.

I think I'm just not calling the right parts (subscribing and unsubscribing tracks etc) at the right times, but I can't find much in the docs about this.

So, basically here's the flow of what I expect to happen from the web app end:

- The local caller retrieves an access token; this prompts the creation of the room.
- The Room object which is returned when the room is created contains the local participant object, which I assign to LocalCaller.participant. This prompts LocalParticipant to subscribe to tracks etc.
- If the Remote Caller has already joined, then they are immediately added to RemoteCaller.participant; otherwise the page waits until they join and then adds them.
- If the Remote Caller ends the call, the 'newRoom.on('participantDisconnected', remoteDisconnected)' callback is hit, and it removes theremote participant information and sets the call status to 'Patient Disconnected'.  At this point the Local Caller is still connected to the room.
- If the Local Caller ends the call, the function 'handleEndCall' is hit, and disconnects the room from the call.  Then endCall is called and attempts to stop the video and audio tracks.

The final step is what doesn't seem to work, as the local user remains connected.

How can I handle this?  What's the correct order for subscribe, unsubscribe, attach and remove tracks?  Does the web app need to handle the remote caller leaving the call, or does the mobile app handle that?

Comment: When you say that the final step doesn't work and the user remains connected to the room, have you looked further into that? Is `call.room.disconnect()` definitely getting called? If it helps, I have an [example application](https://github.com/philnash/twilio-video-react-hooks/blob/master/src/VideoChat.js) that is simpler than this, but is build out through React hooks too.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check out your app and compare them.